# Linux command not working

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Why is this `for ((;;)); do sl; done;` not working? I try to list all files in Ubuntu?

Comment: sl on my system is drawing a little train on my screen, it is not to list files of directory. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/displays-animations-when-accidentally-you-type-sl-instead-of-ls.html

Comment: Because you typed `sl` instead of `ls`?

Comment: What do you expect? What do you observe? What does `sl` do? List of all files can be obtained with `find /`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because:

1. The command is `ls` not `sl` (i.e. LiSt)
2. You have an infinite loop, but no requirement for one (in your question) so you really only need.

This:

```
ls
```

If you want to run the command over and over to look for changes, you would be better off with:

```
watch ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify an error message, so it's hard to say, but I assume that it's not working because you don't have a program named `sl` installed in any directories in your `$PATH`.

Maybe you meant `ls` instead?